# Python List : Why does the element not changed at the index position?

Tags: python, list, indexing

```
single = [1,5,6]
single[:][0] += 5
print(single)
```

I am unable to understand why is the element at index position 0 [0] not changing and also this code doesn't give out any type of error?

Comment: Because you create a copy of the list with `single[:]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that `single[:]` **copies the original list**, so you're only changing a value in the replica without touching the original.

```
single[0] += 5
```

Should be correct

If you want to store the copy, save it:

```
another = single[:]
another[0] += 5
```

Comment: Is there any way to access the new copy?

Comment: @AshUpadhyay Assign it to a variable (identifier).

Comment: trying to find a way but couldn't, I am trying to get the copy of `single[:][0] += 5` while `single[:][0]` is on the left hand side